# Play touch sound whenever the user interacts with screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, user-interface

I want to play sound in android whenever user touches the screen irrespective of which app they are in. Like making it the UI touch sound. so that my app keeps running in the background and playing sound whenever user interacts with screen. where do i the code? what to write? pls help. This is for android. And i'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible. You can intercept touch events only in your Activity.
Similar questions had been already asked
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-beginners/H45Xwm43NGQ

Comment: But i can always run it in background right like playing music in bg

Comment: You can run in background, but you can be notified when user touches the screen only when your Activity is in front, or if someone clicked in your home screen / lock screen widget.

Comment: ok can i atleast point the default touch sound to some other sound without rooting?

Comment: also with rooting. Like overwriting the touch sound file in default location?

Comment: Without rooting - no. With root access you can replace any file. But it's hard to tell whether the default "touch" sound is available in filesystem, and where is it located. But event if you do find, doubt it will stay in the same place across different devices and OS versions. And it's a bad idea to replace the system files just like that. If your app will be uninstalled - it would be hardly possible for a user to recover the default sound.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Android does not allow you to intercept touch events on the screen when outside your own app as this would allow malicious apps to take over all other apps and render the phone useless.

Furthermore, it would very quickly get annoying for the users, particularly if they're playing a game or something that requires a lot of touch events taking place.

Comment: it is a very good thing that the API's don't allow to develop such crazy ideas.

Comment: @DoctororDrive Yep. I don't even know how people come up with stuff like intercepting all touch events. I've even seen people who want to disable the home button. Why would you ever want to do that?